# Sourcing .sh script using . is giving wrong value

Tags: linux, shell

I have written below script to use the value as per below code but when i am running this .sh script to set the env i am able to get correct value for LIC_FILE but am not getting the same value for LM_FILE

```
if [ "$SITE" == "INDIA" ]; then
  set LIC_FILE=5280@india
  set LM_FILE=${LIC_FILE}
else
  set LIC_FILE=5280@sj
  set LM_FILE=${LIC_FILE}
fi
```

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Normal, your vars are local. Use export instead set

```
$ vi toto.sh
$ . toto.sh 
$ echo $LM_FILE
5280@sj
$ cat toto.sh 
if [ "$SITE" == "INDIA" ]; then
  export LIC_FILE="5280@india"
  export LM_FILE=${LIC_FILE}
else
  export LIC_FILE="5280@sj"
  export LM_FILE=${LIC_FILE}
fi
```

Comment: i followed your suggestions, but now i am getting following error: LM_FILE: Undefined variable

Comment: what's your shell ?